# Check prime number for large values in java without using built-in functions.

Tags: java, primes

**I want to write a java program to check prime number for large values.** I had written this code, but there are errors in my code. Please help me in solving that so that it works fine for large values.

Also, **is my approach right for checking prime number for large numbers without built-in functions?**

> Other possible solutions/approaches, please.

My_Code:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheckPrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int flag=0;
        BigInteger input;
        try{
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a valid positive number: ");
        String strinput=sc.nextLine();
        input = new BigInteger(strinput);

        sc.close();
        if(input.equals(0) ||input.equals(1)){                      
          System.out.println(input+" is not a prime number.");
            }
        else{
            for(BigInteger i=2; i < input.divide(2); i++){  
                if(input.remainder(2) == 0){
                    System.out.println(input+" is not a prime number.");
                    flag=1;
                    break;                      
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                    System.out.println(input +" is a prime number.");               
            }
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Please enter only valid positive number: ");
        }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Thank you...!!!");      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For big numbers use the idea that, given n, n is prime iff it is not divisible by any prime in range of 0 to sqrt(n)

Comment: Trial division is likely to be too slow to determine the primality of big integers. A good algorithm for that case is the Miller-Rabin algorithm, which you can find with help from Google or by looking at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/primenumbers.pdf).

Comment: Can you post the exact errors you're getting in your question?

Comment: First, you should post your error. Your approach should be checking input/2 numbers to see whether they are divisible by some numbers. It's right but it's not the best. Check other prime algorithms for better performance. In the for loop, you should check input.remainder(i) instead of input.remainder(2).

Comment: You are using .equals to compare BigInteger and an int, it will always evaluate to false, you use compareTo to compare two BigInteger values, also make your question more clear. "I want to write a java program to check prime number for large values." ????

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

1. Check divisibility by small primes up to, say, 5,000.  This finds the easy ones.
2. Optionally, run a single Fermat test, base 2.  This will eliminate some more composites at less cost than a Miller-Rabin test.
3. If the number is not yet flagged as composite then run repeated Miller-Rabin tests to the level of accuracy you need.  If you run 64 tests then the chances of an error are less than 1 in 2^128.

You might also want to look at a copy of [Crandall and Pomerance](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387252827) which is very useful in this area.

Answer (score 0):

**Check prime number for large values in java without using built-in functions.**

```java
    import java.math.*;
    public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = "1901971054862837232353308517";
        BigInteger num = new BigInteger(n);
        boolean flag = false;
        if(num.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
          System.out.println("not prime");
          return;
        } else if(num.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(2))) {
          System.out.println("prime");
          return;
        } else {
          for(
            BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
            (i.multiply(i)).compareTo(num)!=1;
            i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE)
        ) {
          if((num.mod(i)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            System.out.println("not prime");
            flag = true;
            break; 
          }
        }
        if(!flag)
          System.out.println("prime");
        }
    }
```

**More better way**
use isProbablePrime(int certainty) method of BigInteger class.

```java
    import java.math.*;
    public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = "1901971054862837232353308517";
        BigInteger num = new BigInteger(n);
        // let certainty value be 100
        // the probability for getting prime P = (1 – (1/2)^certainty)
        System.out.println(num.isProbablePrime(100));
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**
true